# Jenkins Error: Process Leaked Filed Description when running an ANT call

Tags: perl, ant, jenkins

I'm currently receiving a "Process Leaked File Description" error whenevery I'm trying to call my ANT script from a Perl script in Jenkins. The job actually finishes currectly, but it's erroring in Jenkins. The Perl script calls something similar to

```
exe("CALL ant -buildfile C:\\build.xml");
```

I have tried googling this Jenkins issue elsewhere and none of the things I have tried appear to work. Anyone have anything else I can try?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build

Answer (score 1):

You should not call ant from a perl script.
Jenkins has a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin) for ant builds.

If your script generates the build.xml you can set up two actions in your project config. The first with the script to generate the buildfile and the second to execute ant on it.

Comment: The build path for the build files and a properties file is reliant to a varable. Using the ant plugin it does not appear that I can pass the entered varaible in to the build path. I've tried C:\%Envrionemnt%\build.xml and it doesn't recognize the variable

Comment: nevermind, it accepts a variable as $variable instead of %variable

Comment: So if I use this, the ant call is suppose to take in a .properties file for most of it's values. I'm struggeling to figure out how to import this properties file correctly.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is an option for this in Perl? I've been requested to keep it in perl.